# 1993 collectors edition sealed box

Tags: magic-the-gathering, pricing

My husband found 2 of the 1993 collectors edition boxes (still sealed, but small rips at the seems on the top). I was hoping you could tell me how much they are worth and where the best places to go to sell them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out a fair price for my Magic the Gathering cards?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/how-do-i-find-out-a-fair-price-for-my-magic-the-gathering-cards)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.abugames.com/item262815-new/0/86-magic/(MTG)---Collectors'-Edition-International-Set-Box.html), it's sold for $3,800.00. I'm guessing yours will fetch a few hundred less (they are retail and try to sell for profit after all).

Things to know. **Don't open them**. The value is on being sealed. They all contain a full set of cards, so there is no chance of getting card X or Y, there is no gamble, they are all there. That means you also have 1 ultra rare "Black Lotus" in there, but here is the catch, all those cards have gold trims in the back, and square corners. This makes them possible to distinguish from "regular" magic cards. They can't be played with on tournaments (for example) and the black lotus is worth far less ($400.00) than the "real" one ($125,000.00)..

I'd sell them on eBay, although if you don't have a good seller's reputation, it'll be a hard sell.

Answer (score 0):

That is likely worth quite a bit of cash.

The best place to see the prices of cards is TCGPlayer.com. Look at mid to low leverl. The best place to make the most money off of something like that once you have found a reasonable price is to post it on ebay honestly. If you want to accept much less but unload it quickly, go to a local card shop.