# Can't find the specific price for MTG japanese cards

Tags: magic-the-gathering, pricing

Hello so I have a few Japanese MTG cards from the year 2000. Among them is a Mountain #344 (from Invasion) illustrated by Jeff Miracola in foil. The English version's value is 1.49$ and I've read that due to rarity Japanese versions cost up to double the price.

I also can't find prices for other cards that I have that probably don't have much value which are some Dragon Quest Card Game cards including a foil one, some Monster Collection Trading Card Game cards, and some Kikaider The Animation cards. I would appreciate any orientation into finding if they have any value other than nostalgic.

PS: Just to clarify all those cards are in japanese

Comment: Possibly related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3161/how-do-i-find-out-a-fair-price-for-my-magic-the-gathering-cards?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

While it is sometimes the case, not all foreign cards are actually worth more than there English counterparts. Nonetheless, older cards definitely might be.

While you can check eBay, this is likely your best source:

http://www.hareruyamtg.com/en/

If you can't find a reference anywhere, check other foreign languages of that card, such as korean or russian.

Comment: Addendum: Check other _similar_ foreign languages of that card.  Value varies wildly between languages and over time.  In brief: Romance languages (southwestern Europe, e.g. Spanish, French, ITalian) are almost always less.  Chinese (both T-Chinese and S-Chinese) are usually less as well, although T-Chinese is sometimes worth more (S-Chinese is never worth more).  Korean is worth more, but the premium decreases over time (older Korean is worth more than newer Korean).  Russian and German are just blanket worth more.  Older Japanese is more, new Japanese is actually less.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, card games in Japan come and go faster than hamburgers at McDonalds, and power creep in those games that do survive is usually fairly rampant and unchecked.  If your non-MTG cards are more than a couple years old, chances are that either the game is dead, or the game has power creeped to the point at which those cards are no longer relevant (if they ever were).  They are probably worthless.

As for the MTG ones, check Hareruya (hareruyamtg.com), they're basically the SCG of Japan.